# can we use advisory recordlocking without usleep() to alternate between the parent and the child?

Tags: c, linux

I am learning "***Advanced Programming in Unix Environment***", and have a problem with exercise no.17 in chapter 15.

The exercise ask reader to "***use advisory recordlocking to alternate between the parent and the child***".

And i found that it can not be done without using usleep(). **There is nothing to stop kernel continually scheduling parent after unlocking the record**, and vice versa.

Does anyone has the answer? Thanks in advance.

HERE is my code:

**ex17.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "ch14/lock.h"

#define NLOOPS 1000
#define SIZE sizeof(long)               /* size of shared memory area */

static int update(long *ptr)
{
    return (*ptr)++;                    /* return value before increment */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd, counter, lockFd;
    pid_t pid;
    void *area;


    if((fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR)) < 0)
    {
        perror("open error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((area = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap error");
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd);                          /*can close /dev/zero now that it's mapped */

    if((lockFd = open("ex17.lock", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644)) < 0)
    {
        perror("open error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* insure parent runs first */
    writew_lock(lockFd, 0, SEEK_SET, 1);                        /* first byte in the lock file represent parent */
    writew_lock(lockFd, 1, SEEK_SET, 1);                        /* second byte in the lock file represent child */

    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    }else if(pid > 0){                  /* parent */
        for(int i = 0; i<NLOOPS; i+=2)
        {
            writew_lock(lockFd, 0, SEEK_SET, 1);
            readw_lock(lockFd, 1, SEEK_SET, 1);

            if((counter = update((long*)area)) != i)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "parent: expected %d, got %d\n", i, counter);
                exit(1);
            }else{
                printf("%s got %d\n", "parent", counter);
            }
            un_lock(lockFd, 1, SEEK_SET, 1);
            usleep(1000);  /*if without this line, there is nothing to stop kernel continually scheduling parent.*/
            readw_lock(lockFd, 0, SEEK_SET, 1);
        }
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    } else {
        for(int i=1; i<NLOOPS+1; i+=2)
        {
            writew_lock(lockFd, 1, SEEK_SET, 1);
            readw_lock(lockFd, 0, SEEK_SET, 1);

            if((counter = update((long*)area)) != i)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "child: expected %d, got %d\n", i, counter);
                exit(1);
            }else{
                printf("%s got %d\n", "child", counter);
            }
            un_lock(lockFd, 0, SEEK_SET, 1);
            usleep(1000);
            readw_lock(lockFd, 1, SEEK_SET, 1);
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

**ch14/lock.h**

```
#ifndef CH14_LOCK_H_INCLUDED
#define CH14_LOCK_H_INCLUDED

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int lock_reg(int, int, int, off_t, int, off_t);
pid_t lock_test(int, int, off_t, int, off_t);

#define read_lock(fd, offset, whence, len) lock_reg((fd), F_SETLK, F_RDLCK, (offset), (whence), (len))
#define readw_lock(fd, offset, whence, len) lock_reg((fd), F_SETLKW, F_RDLCK, (offset), (whence), (len))
#define write_lock(fd, offset, whence, len) lock_reg((fd), F_SETLK, F_WRLCK, (offset), (whence), (len))
#define writew_lock(fd, offset, whence, len) lock_reg((fd), F_SETLKW, F_WRLCK, (offset), (whence), (len))
#define un_lock(fd, offset, whence, len) lock_reg((fd), F_SETLK, F_UNLCK, (offset), (whence), (len))

#define is_read_lockable(fd, offset, whence, len) (lock_test((fd), F_RDLCK, (offset), (whence), (len)) == 0)
#define is_write_lockable(fd, offset, whence, len) (lock_test((fd), F_WRLCK, (offset), (whence), (len)) == 0)


#endif // CH14_LOCK_H_INCLUDED
```

**ch14/lock.c**

```
#include "lock.h"

int lock_reg(int fd, int cmd, int type, off_t offset, int whence, off_t len)
{
    struct flock lock;

    lock.l_type = type;                            /* F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK */
    lock.l_whence = whence;                    /* byte offset, relative to l_whence */
    lock.l_start = offset;                        /* byte offset, relative to l_whence */
    lock.l_len = len;                                /* #bytes (0 means to EOF) */

    return fcntl(fd, cmd, &lock);
}

pid_t lock_test(int fd, int type, off_t offset, int whence, off_t len)
{
    struct flock lock;

    lock.l_type = type;                            /* F_RDLCK OR F_WRLCK */
    lock.l_start = offset;                        /* byte offset, relative to l_whence */
    lock.l_whence = whence;                     /* SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END */
    lock.l_len = len;                                /* #bytes (0 means to EOF) */

    if(fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &lock) < 0)
    {
        perror("fcntl error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(lock.l_type == F_UNLCK)
    {
        return 0;                                    /* false, region isn't locked by another proc */
    }else{
        return lock.l_pid;                            /* true, return pid of lock owner */
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never checking the locks.  *Advisory* locks are not enforced, and right now you're ignoring the locks you've set; they serve no purpose.  Once you add the check, you'll probably need a (very short) time delay to prevent busy looping, since there are no blocking calls (most likely, you should incorporate that loop into a function, making it effectively a blocking call).

Comment: hi, @goldilocks. Thanks for answering. Advisory locks are enforced only if they were held by different processes. By "checking the locks" do you mean i should check the owner of the lock? Even if i add lock owner checking, that does not eliminate the need of usleep() calls in the code.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks, maybe your ways is the best solution for this. But don't understand why the author use this as a exercises for the book.

Comment: TBH while it's a challenging exercise, I don't think you'd be learning much that you'll actually apply later.  File locks are an  old concept with limited use value -- using them to synchronize processes, as here, is sort of silly.  That is better done using more direct forms of IPC, or multi-threading.  So it's nice to know about, but you don't need to spend a lot of time on it.  Anyway, I've added an answer explaining what I meant by checking the locks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advisory lock implementations differ from one unix-like OS to another, but they usually [are not mandatory by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems), and this is the case with linux.  `man fcntl` contains a section for advisory locks and mandatory locks; from the beginning of the latter (where "above" refers to the former):

> The above record locks may be  either  advisory  or  mandatory,  and  are  advisory  by default. Advisory locks are not enforced and *are useful only between cooperating processes.*

This means in order for the lock to be effective, each cooperating process must check to see if it can acquire one before it does so.  `man fcntl` says some things about this for the `F_GETLK` call:

> F_GETLK (struct flock *)
>
> On input to this call, *lock* describes a lock we would like to place on the file.  If the  lock could  be  placed, fcntl() **does not actually place it,** but returns F_UNLCK in the l_type field of lock and leaves the other fields of the structure unchanged.  If one or  more  incompatible
>   locks  would  prevent  this lock being placed, then fcntl() returns details about one of these locks in the l_type, l_whence, l_start, and l_len fields of lock and sets l_pid to be the  PID of the process holding that lock.

So the struct you submit using F_GETLK may have some fields changed to indicate a result -- this is what you need to check.  If it succeeds, you can then call with F_SETLK to actually apply the lock.<sup>1</sup>  If it doesn't succeed, you need to wait until it does, and none of these calls are *blocking*, meaning they return immediately regardless of the situation.  This is where the necessity of a short sleep comes in, because if you simply loop around checking the lock over and over again, you will be *busy looping* a processor (maxing it out doing nothing).  However, if you throw in a 5 or 10 ms passive delay, the loop will be mostly doing nothing passively (i.e., without maxing out a processor).  This delay should be only after a failed check; if the check succeeds, immediately set the lock.

All that can go in a single function.  It does not take care of getting the processes to steadily alternate, but this is actually sort of a contrived criteria: if you wanted to accomplish that goal in "real life", you would not go about it this way.  However, it's not impossible; the first thing I would try would be to use a sleep at the beginning of the function which is several times longer than the one in the loop, so that a process which releases a lock and then goes to acquire it again will be delayed longer than a process which was concurrently trying to get it in the check/set loop.

---

<sup>1. Unfortunately, that implies a potential race condition whereby one process may set a lock in between another process's check and set calls -- a weakness of this system.</sup>